# Suggest appropriate index on my database

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table product

```
Product(id  BIGINT,
         ... Some more columns here
         expired  DATE);
```

I want to create index on expired field for faster retrieval.

Majority of time my where clause is

```
       ...
       WHERE  (expired IS NULL OR expired > now());
```

Please can you suggest which index is more suitable for me.

When I execute explain analyze for the above query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 1
FROM   product 
WHERE  (expired IS NULL) OR (expired > now());
```

it gave me following result. In which it is not using index which I have created.

```
Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..190711.22 rows=5711449 width=0) (actual time=0.009..8653.380 rows=7163105 loops=1)
   Filter: ((expired IS NULL) OR (expired > now()))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 43043
  Planning time: 0.117 ms
Execution time: 15679.478 ms
(5 rows)
```

I guess that is because of "OR" condition. i tried to create function base index but it gave me following error

```
   ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

Is there any alternate way we can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `WHERE` clause to look like this:

```
... WHERE COALESCE(expired, DATE 'infinity') > current_date;
```

This is equivalent to your query, but now you can use the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON product (COALESCE(expired, DATE 'infinity'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the default B-tree index is the most appropriate one for you; hash indexes only handle "equals" comparisons, and the GiST and GIN indexes are for more complex data types that what you are using:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html

In fact the B-tree is the default, so all you need to do is something like:

```
CREATE INDEX Products_expired_idx ON TABLE Products (expired)
```

Comment: When i explain analyzed simple query with cluase i have given it is not utilizing index like

Comment: Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..190711.22 rows=5711449 width=0) (actual time=0.009..8653.380 rows=7163105 loops=1)
   Filter: ((expired IS NULL) OR (expired > now()))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 43043
 Planning time: 0.117 ms
 Execution time: 15679.478 ms
(5 rows)

Comment: The query planner can choose not to use the index even if you have one; see https://robots.thoughtbot.com/why-postgres-wont-always-use-an-index for a good explanation. If your stats are out of date, you can run ``VACUUM FULL Products`` and try the query again.

Comment: Did VACCUM FULL but no sucess. I guess this is because "OR" condition.

Comment: @GaneshJadhav you have 7M+ rows, from which 43K are filtered out by your predicate. With these statistics, PostgreSQL will most likely choose the seq. scan (because it needs almost all of the rows) anyway.